# Flutter mapping json to model array 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Tags: arrays, list, flutter

I am reading a json with few different arrays. So I want to map it to its individual model list. Thus first I created the list for e.g. as below.

```
class Summary {


  final String totalDuration;
  final String totalMileage;
  //final String fleetID;

  Summary({this.totalDuration, this.totalMileage});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'totalDuration': totalDuration,
        'totalMileage': totalMileage,

      };

  factory Summary.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Summary(
      totalDuration: json['totalDuration'],
      totalMileage: json['totalMileage'],

    );
  }
}
```

I have managed to call my api and below is how my json results look like its not the complete one as I wanted to make it brief.

```
"totalSummary": 6,
    "Summary": [
        {
            "totalDuration": "2549",            
            "totalMileage": "22.898"
        },
        { 
            "totalDuration": "11775",
            "totalMileage": "196.102"
        },
        {
            "totalDuration": "17107",
            "totalMileage": "232.100"
        },
        {  
            "totalDuration": "34870",
            "totalMileage": "177.100"
        },
        {
            "totalDuration": "33391",
             "totalMileage": "168.102"
        },
        {
            "totalDuration": "13886",
            "totalMileage": "77.398"
        }
    ],
    "totalDetails": 16,
    "details": [
          ..........
        ]
```

Below is how I wrote to populate the summary array.

```
final fullJson = await NetworkUtils.post(url,token,data);
        print("fullJson"+fullJson.toString());
        try{
        Summary summary1 = new Summary.fromJson(fullJson['Summary']);

         print(summary1.totalMileage);
        }
        catch(Err){
          print("Erro is at"+Err.toString());
        }
```

I end up getting `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the response returned contains a List of Map instead of a map .

change your line `Summary summary1 = new Summary.fromJson(fullJson['Summary']);`

to `Summary summary1 = new Summary.fromJson(fullJson['Summary'][i]);`

where i can be any value between 0 to the numbers of objects inside Summary minus one.

To get the full list of `Summary` objects do this:

```
int totalSummaryCount = fullJson['totalSummary'];
List<Summary> list = new List<Summary>.generate(totalSummaryCount, (index)=>Summary.fromJson(fullJson['Summary'][index]));
```

Comment: how to do it for the whole list at one go rather than one by one?

Comment: ok I shall try. So when I recall the api do I need to first clear the previous List<Sumarry>

Comment: What is the correct command to fully clear any of the List<Summary> etc mean after each api I dont want any old value in it at all

Comment: you can use `list.clear();` when you receive response from API or you could just create a class variable and update it with obtained result. You can see official List documentation [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/List-class.html)

Comment: how to clear cause we define as List<Summary> list = new List<Summary> ?

Comment: I mean how to refer to any old list ? Cause each time is a new list ? How to know any old list of Summary ?

Comment: Write this `List<Summary> list = []` in your State class and then change the line in code I provided from `List<Summary> list = new List<Summary>.generate(totalSummaryCount, (index)=>Summary.fromJson(fullJson['Summary'][index]));` to `list = new List<Summary>.generate(totalSummaryCount, (index)=>Summary.fromJson(fullJson['Summary'][index]));`. This will replace the previous list with the updated one.